# "void is an invalid type for the variable buttonOK" - trying to close dialog after clicking button

Tags: java, android, android-button

Some time ago i've made a simple dialog. Everything looks fine, but i'm meeting troubles after trying to close it. The error is 
`"void is an invalid type for the variable buttonOK"`.

Hmm, better i'll give a link to screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZf8r.png

The code of dialog:

```
public void aboutApp(View view) {

    // custom dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.aboutapp);
                dialog.setTitle("about  ");

                // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
                text.setText("bla bla bla ");
                ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);



                    @Override
                    public void buttonOK(View view) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }


                dialog.show();
}
```

What should I do to make it works?

PS I've got error at `public void buttonOK(View view)`, extacly at `view` - `Duplicate local variable view` Should I rename it in, for example `view2`?

### Ok, i found solution.

The problem was (as noticed **Ridcully**) that defined method `buttonOK()` in another method `aboutApp()`, what can't be done in java (uach, now I know it :D).

I simply replaced the code: `@Override
                    public void buttonOK(View view) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }`

to:

```
Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
                // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view2) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

Now it works, thx all for help!

Comment: What button do you want to call `buttonOK()`? One of the default dialog buttons or is it a button you define in `aboutapp.xml`?

Comment: Emm, this one defined in aboutapp.xml

Comment: Are you trying to use the `android:onClick="buttonOK"` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined a method (`buttonOK()`) within another method (`aboutApp()`). This is not possible in Java. The compiler tries to make sense of this and supposes somhow that `buttonOk` is meant as a variable -- thus the misleading error message.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, but how can i manage to close the dialog by clicking button?

Comment: See the API Docs (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). They have also some helpful examples there on how to add buttons and how to handle clicking on them.

Answer (score 1):

Your using dialogs incorrectly.  Here's an example for you.

```java
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //TODO Handle click here

    }
});

dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to use the [`android:onClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick) attribute with `"buttonOK"`, you **must** declare `public void buttonOK(View v) {}` as a regular method in your class. (Currently you are trying to nest it inside `aboutApp()`, also understand that you cannot nest methods in Java.)

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    Dialog dialog;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { ... }

    public void aboutApp(View view) {
        // custom dialog
        dialog = new Dialog(context);
        ...
    }

    // Move your method here:
    public void buttonOK(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```